# Stopping CSRF checking for subdomains

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

For our Laravel 5.3 API, I want to remove the need for CSRF tokens since everything is handled with OAuth2 and JWT.

Currently the API operates on the subdomain: `api.example.com`

I tried this but it still requests CSRF tokens:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        'api.*'
    ];
}
```

I'd also like to be able to disable the CSRF protection when I am doing random route tests on the main app which is on `app.example.dev`, but adding `'app.*'` to `$except` also doesn't work.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the `shouldPassThrough` method in the `BaseVerifier` class, where-in it would support a subdomain in `$except` such as `api.yourdomain.com`

```
/**
 * Determine if the request has a URI that should pass through CSRF verification.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function shouldPassThrough($request)
{
    foreach ($this->except as $except) {
        if (Str::is($except, $request->url())) {
            // break out of CSRF check
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `return false` portion be outside the foreach loop?